# Smooth transition from anisotropic cosmological model to Euclidean

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Does anyone know of an attempt in the literature to construct an equation of state for classical matter, which upon substitution into Einstein's equations gives a solution which is spatially homogeneous anisotropic for $t<0$ and spatially Euclidean for $t\ge0$? In other words, does there exist a classical matter (hypothetical) that can drive the universe from a homogeneous anisotropic past to Euclidean present? It may happen that the matter undergoes a phase transition at $t=0$.

More mathematically, it is easy to construct a smooth spacetime $(\mathbb{R}^4,g)$ of which the spatial isometry group at $t<0$ is a Bianchi group (say, Heisenberg), and for $t\ge0$ is the Euclidean group $\operatorname{E}(3)$. The question is whether anyone has come up with an equation of state which would generate such a solution of Einstein's equations.

Thank you.